# AWS elasticbean does not handles Flask static assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, static, assets

I created simple flask site with could of assets/static files. Uploaded it to EC2, server renders templates correctly, but static files absolutely unavailable.

I connected via SSH and checked whether setup all corrent. Path to application root is `/opt/python/current/app/`, full path to CSS file `/opt/python/current/app/mysite/static/css/stylesheet.css`.

Corresponding alias specified in web console and transfered to Apache's wsgi.conf:

`Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/mysite/static
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/mysite/static>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>`

Trying to get al least CSS file (http://xxx.xxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/css/stylesheet.css) - got 404.

Check whether files are in place and static folder pointing to correct location: adding `Options + Indexes` to directory section above, opening url `http://xxx.xxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/`, and see content of my static folder: `css, js, lib`.

One more check: adding file `1.css` to static root, opening in browser as directory, see that my file appeared. Trying to get it clicking on this file - got 404 again!

Neither any additional setting was added, nor dotfiles. All dynamic pages are retrieved succesfully.

How to handle static files with EC2?

Comment: `Elastic Beanstalk != EC2` have you checked your security groups?

Comment: @Snuggert security group applied to entire web server instance. I.e. if I missed security group I did not received answer from server at all. My issue related ONLY to static content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple and dumb: in configuration section where `/static/` alias defined I missed trailing slash.

Incorrect: `mysite/static`

Correct: `mysite/static/`

Answer (score 0):

Flask serves routes to `(root_folder)/static` and you are pointing your apache config to a route that is `(root_folder)/mysite/static` and flask can't find routes for this location thus 404'ing.

Solutions:

1. change Flask's static folder
2. move current static folder to the `(root_folder)`

Comment: Nope, as I described, when I turned on directory listing I can see all my static files structure. It means that directory points to correct location. Also, flask application runs inside `mysite` folder correctly.